# Undocumented feature of Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int> testdic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
testdic.Add("cat", 1);
testdic.Add("dog", 2);
testdic.Add("rat", 3);
testdic.Remove("cat");
testdic.Add("bob", 4);
```

Fill the dictionary and then remove the first element.  Then add a new element.  Bob then appears at position 1 instead of at the end, therefore it seems to remember removed entries and re-uses that memory space?

Is this documented anywhere because I can't see it on MSDN and has caused me a day of grief because I assumed it would just keep adding to the end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not documented because it's just an implementation detail.

The implementation could change at any time. (And unless you've closely examined the source code then you can't even be sure that your assumptions about the current implementation are accurate.)

The [`Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) type does not guarantee to store its elements in any particular order, and you shouldn't rely on any undocumented behaviour that you happen to observe. A dictionary is a map from keys to values, *not* an ordered list.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration ... [t]he order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Comment: I feel it important to emphasize that this is because you use a dictionary to retrieve data by key. That's the only use you have for it. If you require anything else (like iterating over it), you should probably use a different structure.

Comment: IMHO, Microsoft should have documented that the enumeration order of a `Dictionary` is defined for those instances (and only those instances) where no key has *ever* been deleted. Upholding such a guarantee in that limited usage scenario would not be expensive, but would make it practical for code which dictionaries in a manner consistent with that pattern to define a canonical serialized representation, such that the data stream yielded by deserializing and reserializing a dictionary will match the original.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary is not sorted, so you should never assume anything about the order of the elements.

The implementation is likely to attempt to be the most efficient. This might mean that the current implementation, exhibits the behaviour you are seeing. But it is not documented to do so, so you should not rely on it.